# Windows 7 - Windows XP - sharing - why isn't working?

Tags: windows-7, networking

This is seems to be "hardware" and not "software" / "programming" question, but I need to use this share in my programs, so it is "close to programming".

We had an XP based wireless network.

The server is XP Professional, the clients are XP Home (Notebooks).

This was working well with folder sharing (with user rights, not simple share).

Then we replaced the one of the notebook with Win7/X64 notebook.
First time this can reach the server, and the another client too.

Later I went to another sites, and connect to another servers, another networks.

And then, when I return to this network, I saw that I cannot connect to this server.
Nothing of resources I see, and when try to dbl click on this computer, I got login window, where I can write anything, never I can login...

The interesting part, that:
Another XP home can see the server, can login as quest, or with other user.
The server can see the XP home notebook.
The Win7 can see the notebook's shared folders, and XP home can see the Win7 shared folders.
The server can see the Win7 folders, BUT: the Win7 cannot see the server folders. Cannot see the resources too...

The Win7 is in "work networking group", the group name is not mshome.

I tried everything on the server, I tried to remove MS client, restore it with simple sharing, set guest password, etc., but I lost the possibilities to access this server from Win7.

Does anyone have any idea what I need to see, what I need to set to access these resource - to use them in my programs?

Thanks for every info, link:
  dd

Comment: In `secpol.msc` enable "Logon events" auditing (_not_ "Account Logon"). Go to Event Viewer (`eventvwr.msc`), clear the Security log, try to connect from one machine, refresh log, repeat with other computer. (Pay attention to the "Authentication package" field in events.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this question](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/3730-xp-share-folder-problems.html)

Enable these Services:

- Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol Service
- Routing And Remote Access

Your problem sounds the same as mentioned in the question on this site. This has worked for a number of people. Hope it does the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the log result:

```
System

  - Provider

   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
   [ Guid]  {54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}

   EventID 4625

   Version 0

   Level 0

   Task 12544

   Opcode 0

   Keywords 0x8010000000000000

  - TimeCreated

   [ SystemTime]  2010-06-09T08:02:32.385230700Z

   EventRecordID 4542

   Correlation

  - Execution

   [ ProcessID]  684
   [ ThreadID]  4628

   Channel Security

   Computer SuperDev

   Security


- EventData

  SubjectUserSid S-1-0-0
  SubjectUserName -
  SubjectDomainName -
  SubjectLogonId 0x0
  TargetUserSid S-1-0-0
  TargetUserName User
  TargetDomainName ZSERVER
  Status 0xc000006d
  FailureReason %%2304
  SubStatus 0x0
  LogonType 3
  LogonProcessName
  AuthenticationPackageName NTLM
  WorkstationName SUPERDEV
  TransmittedServices -
  LmPackageName -
  KeyLength 0
  ProcessId 0x0
  ProcessName -
  IpAddress 192.168.56.1
  IpPort 2321
```

Is this enough information?

Comment: this is not an answer. Edit the question and include necessary information in its content